# 3D volume slicing: TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

I would like to select some slices from a 3D volume by indexing with this instruction:

```
ini=p[0,0]
fin=p[0,:-1]
aux=img[:,:,ini.astype(int):fin.astype(int)]
```

Where "ini" and "fin" come from a numpy array containing the slices of interest.

The error that python throw is:
**TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index**

When I try the same but with the numbers directly, i.e:
`aux=img[:,:,20:30]`
It works.

Could you help me please?
Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: What is the dtype of the  ndarray `p` ? If each array of the 2nd dimension has more than one element I assume that `fin` is an array with more than one element, so the astype will only cast the inner elements and you can't use it as an index.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have the same issue as you, did you figure out how to do it ?